# Event bubbling in react doesn't stop using e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, dom-events

I have an `<input>` under a `<th>`, the input has an `onChange` event, however when the input is clicked a `click` event is being fired on the `<th>` tag. How to stop the `click` event from going up the DOM tree to the parent event-listener?

```
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <table>
      <th onClick={()=>alert('fire')}>
        name
        <input onChange={e=>{e.preventDefault();alert('change text')}}/>
      </th>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Try to active the input https://codesandbox.io/s/wq3rj2m00w

Comment: Does no one realize that onclick and onchange are two different unrelated events?

Comment: @KevinB how to stop firing 'fire'?

Comment: Add an onclick handler and stop the propagation within it. the onchange is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @KevinB onChange fire when you focus the input, see here https://codesandbox.io/s/wq3rj2m00w

Comment: For me, only the click event is firing when you focus the input, and only if the act of focusing the input is done via clicking. Not by tabbing, and the change event doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the `th` click handler to fire when it is clicked on directly, you can check the target:

```
<th onClick={e => {
   if (e.currentTarget === e.target) {
     alert('fire');
   }
}}>
```

The other option is to add a click handler to the input with a stopPropagation call:

```
<input onChange={e=>{e.preventDefault();alert('change text')}} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}/>
```

MDN details on `currentTarget`:

> Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: How well do you think first method will work, if the th has a span inside it with a width smaller than that of th.

Comment: The first method only fires the alert if the click is directly on the `th`, not on anything inside it.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Your method of adding an ID works well too.

Answer (score 2):

So the thing is that when you try to focus on the input by clicking on it, an onClick event is triggered on input and propogated to the parent,

You have two possible solutions:

**First:** Add an onClick event on the input and stopPropagation of the event.

```
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <table>
      <th onClick={()=>alert('fire')}>
        name
        <input onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}} onChange={e=>{alert('change text')}}/>
      </th>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

or

**Second:** Check the `target` in the `onClick` event before taking an action

```
const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <table>
      <th onClick={(e)=>{if(e.target.id !== 'input') {alert('fire')}}}>
        name
        <input id="input" onChange={e=>{alert('change text')}}/>
      </th>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I don't understand, why a negative vote for this, please put a comment if you are doing it, so that I can improve the post