# Prevent parent click event from firing when checking child checkbox in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, is it possible to disable a redirection when a switch button is placed inside a redirection component?

I have a clickable TableRow which redirects to another component and a switch button (checkbox) inside, like this:

The `TableRow` component with his `TableCell` and the `Switch` button inside:

```
<TableRow
   className="h-40 cursor-pointer"
   hover
   role="checkbox"
   aria-checked={isSelected}
   tabIndex={-1}
   key={n.id}
   selected={isSelected}
   onClick={event => handleClick(n)}
>
  <TableCell component="th" scope="row" align="left">
    <Switch
     checked={state.checkedB}
     onChange={handleChange("checkedB")}
     value="checkedB"
    />
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Here is the `handleChange` function and the state of the Switch button:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
   checkedB: true,
});

const handleChange = name => event => {
   setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

And here is the `handleClick` function in the `TableRow` component which redirect to another component:

```
function handleClick(item){
    props.history.push('/apps/fournisseurs/'+item.id+'/'+ item.handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to stop propagation (`event.stopPropagation()`) when you click on the `Switch`. This will stop the event from bubbling up the chain and will essentially "ignore" the parent click handler (`onClick` in this case).

```
const handleChange = name => event => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
};
```

```
<TableRow
   className="h-40 cursor-pointer"
   hover
   role="checkbox"
   aria-checked={isSelected}
   tabIndex={-1}
   key={n.id}
   selected={isSelected}
   onClick={event => handleClick(n)}
>
  <TableCell component="th" scope="row" align="left">
    <Switch
     checked={state.checkedB}
     onChange={handleChange("checkedB")}
     value="checkedB"
     onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
    />
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

**Edit:**

After finding another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837732/1554860), unfortunately the way for the above code to work would be to add an additional handler to the `Switch` component of `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}`

Comment: Thank you for your help but this way doesn't work. Maybe because `Switch`'s parent is `TableCell` and no `TableRow`, no ? I don't know...

Comment: Ahh yeah, I see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44698130/1554860) that the `click` event will fire before the `change` event. A rather poor solution would be to add `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to the `<Switch` in addition to your `onChange` that is already there.